# Dataprep - Schema does not match the recipe on every scheduled run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

I am trying to create an *ETL process*, I have the desired data stored in *Big Query*. Every time I want to run my process in Dataprep this error pops up:

**The schema of the BigQuery table does not match the recipe (...)**

To solve it I have to manually re-import the table from *Big Query*, my question is:

Is there a way to automate the manual re-import of the table on every scheduled run in order to solve this error?

**Note**: I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53936339/the-schema-of-the-bigquery-table-does-not-match-the-recipe) with a similar issue but the solution given was manual and I want an automated solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.